# How to sort nested OrderedDicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am having an issue with sorting nested OrderedDicts.. I am trying to sort both the outermost dictionary, and the following dictionary by a key value in the innermost dictionary. Given the attached snippet, this what I am trying to accomplish: - For all foods, order the food subtypes by highest calorie content (i.e - For Pizza, Pesto should appear first because it has higher calories when compared to cheese. - Order all foods by highest calorie content (i.e - Pizza should appear first as it has a subtype with more calories than any other food). Before I tacked on the outermost dictionary, I was using this to sort just the food types (red,green,pesto,cheese): `OrderedDict(sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1].iteritems()))` . However, I am not sure how to proceed after having tacked on the outermost dictionary.

Comment: You're going to have to show us the structure of d and the Food type for us to know how to help

Comment: There's no "attached snippet".